# filling in a shape drawn by a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Picture of what the code does with the Top Hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXxHH.png) I am working on a project working with Object Oriented Programming and our assignment was to draw a Snowman with the classes primarily being shapes. I have the whole snowman drawn out, but when trying to fill in the square that is the top hat it fills a triangle instead for some reason.

```
import turtle

class Shape(object):

    def __init__(self,  pensize = 1, pencolor = "black"):

        self.pensize = pensize
        self.pencolor = pencolor

class Line(Shape):
    def __init__(self, start = (0.0, 0.0), end = (50.0, 0.0),
                 pencolor = "black", pensize = 1):

        Shape.__init__(self,pensize,pencolor)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __str__(self):
        return "Line(beg:{},end:{})".format(self.start ,self.end)

    def draw(self, pen):
        """draw the line using the provided pen"""
        pen.pensize(self.pensize)
        pen.pencolor(self.pencolor)
        pen.up()
        pen.goto(self.start)
        pen.down()
        pen.goto(self.end)

class Square(object):
    def __init__(self, pos = (0.0,0.0), size = 50):

        self.pos = pos
        x ,y = pos
        self.size = size
        self.side_lines = [Line((x, y), (x, y + size)),  # front, left
                           Line((x, y), (x + size, y)),  # front, bottom
                           Line((x + size, y), (x + size, y + size)),  # front, right
                           Line((x, y + size), (x + size, y + size))]  # front, top

    def __str__(self):
        return "Square(pos:{},size:{})".format(self.pos, self.size)

    def draw(self, pen):
        for l in self.side_lines:
            l.draw(pen)

class Snow_man(Shape):
    def __init__(self, pos = (0.0, 0.0)):
        self.pos= pos

    def __str__(self):
        return "Drawing a Snowman"

    def draw(self, pen):
        brim = Line((-400, 300), (-200, 300), "black", 5)
        brim.draw(pen)
        pen.color("black")
        pen.begin_fill()
        topHat = Square((-360, 300), 120)
        topHat.draw(pen)
        pen.end_fill()

pen= turtle.Turtle()
snowman= Snow_man()
snowman.draw(pen)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you're calling begin_fill() from the the current location of the turtle which is the end of the hat brim when you want to call begin_fill() at the corner of the square.

So using something like pen.goto(-360, 300) before you use begin_fill() would take turtle to the starting position. then you call begin_fill().

Next its how you draw the lines, it would be better if the lines were drawn from corner to corner rather than going back and forth as a simple example using just fd() and right() commands.

```
being_fill()
fd(50)
right(90)
fd(50)
right(90)
fd(50)
right(90)
fd(50)
end_fill()
```

would fill a square. So i just think you gotta readjust the drawing of you lines in side_lines. Like which coordinates its starts at etc.